# PHP or IIS only allowing server administrators to FTP files from another Server

Tags: php, iis

I'm not sure if this is a PHP or an IIS 7.5 (on Windows 2008 server) problem.  I have a web application that uses AJAX to call a PHP script that ftp's pictures from a remote server.  The pictures are then saved locally and a link is made to them.  Previously I had no issue with the users executing this but this has changed and they can not execute the ftp.  In troubleshooting I temporarily made one of the [trusted] users an administrator on the server and they could execute the ftp.  As far as the ftp goes, the username and password are hard coded and therefore independent of who is using them, as long as I have given them access to my web server.  The users can execute all other PHP and database-related scripts, it's just the ftp portion.  I'm hoping that someone might have some direction for me, thank you in advance.

Comment: No error messages? What has changed? Generally speaking, code doesn't tend to just stop working unless something _somewhere_ has changed, have you updated anything to a newer version recently? Have you migrated to a new server? I doubt this is a PHP related thing, but without seeing how the code is managed it's impossible to tell.

Comment: You should make one thing more clear, since it is confusing: if that is a web application based on php and an http server, then the process is always executed by the services user account, no matter who (which account) triggers the script. If however you really have different user accounts executing the php script, then where does the http server come into play here?

Comment: I haven't changed anything in the code, wondered if there was a change in IIS.  The users would access the web server with services, I control their access to the database information via a service account that they subscribe to.  On the error side, I'm having an issue there.  I am writing errors to the php-error.log but, again, it will only do it for administrators.  I made sure that the service account that they subscribe to had write access to the log location but still no luck getting errors written there, even if I forced a generic write to the log when they executed the php.

Comment: There is also a legacy server group "Power User" that allows the FTP when I assign the service account to it.